# i am using laravel 5.7 framework when i am using setAutoFilter in excel he is give me error

Tags: laravel

count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

```
 return $this - > excel - > create($this - > getReportName(), function($excel) {


     #Set standard properties on the file
     $this - > setProperties($excel);


     #Produce the tab
     # @todo exctract tabs into their own classes
     $excel - > sheet('Program List Report', function($sheet) {
         $sheet - > loadView('reports.program.list.report') 
         - > with('programs', $this - > candidates) 
         - > setAutoFilter() 
         - > freezeFirstRow() 
         - > setColumnFormat($this - > getFormats());
     });


     #Set the includeSql = true to have SQL Printout tab
     # includeSql should NEVER be true
     for production reports
     $this - > includeSqlTab($excel);


     #Make the first sheet active
     $excel - > setActiveSheetIndex(0);

 }) - > store('xlsx', $this - > getReportPath(), true);
```

Comment: See https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/1465.

Comment: never seen anyone write the object operator (or arrow) with whitespaces like you do! `object - > property` :)

Comment: @ceejayoz this is the vendor changes and i did that but issue is not fixed yet. if you have correct solution please give me.